# How to prove the authenticity of a voice recorder file

Tags: voice-manipulation

this is a very important problem.

As consultant in a legal proceedings, I have an audio file created by voice recorder of Apple. The duration of this file is only 20 seconds long; there is the suspect that the original file was 30 seconds long and that the first 10 second was cutted. I should prove it. My instrument is Sonic Visualizer, due to I can see all frequency graph; and Exiftool, due to I can see all meta of file. Exiftool don’t help me (the meta of a genuine Voice file is the same of a cute file by Quick Time). The question is:

In the frequency audio graph there is a particular characteristic / silent sort period / device “signature” / something else at the beginning of a voice file, which is present in all file produced by the recorder of iPhone?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The only way to determine this is to obtain an iPhone and do some test recordings. That way you will be able to see if there is a characteristic signature at the start of each recording. Unfortunately this will be firmware and o/s dependent, so you will need to know the exact firmware of the phone that made the original recording.

Comment: https://www.audioforensicexpert.com/authentication-of-digital-audio-recordings/